# Telerik RadGrid Column Filtering on Text Value of LinkButton

Tags: c#, .net, filter, telerik, radgrid

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Code" SortExpression="Code" UniqueName="Code" AllowFiltering="True">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Code") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

So how can I allow RadGrid to filter the results based on the text value of LinkButton? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you got any event handlers in place? You need some code to handle the click of LinkButton (whether server side or something javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Code" SortExpression="Code" UniqueName="Code" AllowFiltering="True"
        DataField="Code">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Code") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

I have added DataField property in template column. if you get any error in grid then please set **EnableLinqExpressions="false"** in your grid.

Comment: Yep, that's what I figured out as well. We will need to use DataField attribute. I happened to find the solution on Telerik website.